# Convert a string or json value to YAML array for GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to dynamically build secrets into this GitHub action library for my pipeline.

I need to preprocess and generate all the secrets (pulled from AWS). After, I want to dynamically inject those secrets into this GitHub action.

### Node.js script

```
let secrets = generateArrayOfSecrets() //[AWS_KEY=123, API_TOKEN=345]
let envFile = convertToEnvFile(secrets)
fs.writeFileSync(process.env.PUT_FILE || '.env.read', envFile)
```

### Echo output form node.js file

```
echo "::set-output name=SECRETS::$(cat .env.read)"
```

### Dynamically build secrets

```
 - name: Build, Tag, and Push Image to Amazon ECR
   uses: docker/build-push-action@v3   
   with:
     push: true
     secrets: ${{ steps.secret.outputs.SECRETS }}
```

This isn't working, and it is treating it as a single value. My question is, how can I convert a string to a real YAML array? Any help would be greatly appreciated here.

Comment: I fell down this trap. `::set-output` cannot handle carriage return. Pass your data as a single line of JSON, then use `fromJSON` to get the data into your variable. e.g. `secrets: ${{ fromJSON(steps.secret.outputs.SECRETS) }}`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [secrets section on the `docker.build-push-action` action repository](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/blob/master/docs/advanced/secrets.md), you can expose a secret file to the build with the `secret-files` input.

Something like this:

```
        name: Build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          push: true
          secret-files: |
             "MY_SECRET=./secret.txt"
```

As you are already creating an `envFile` with the secrets in your Node script, this solution seems more adapted, as you won't need to parse it to get each secret key/value.

*PS: This secret files needs to follow the [Docker docs build pattern](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#secret)*